# StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 3.2.5 Warning

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I was testing the StanfordNERTagger using the NLTK wrapper and this warning appeared:

```
DeprecationWarning: The StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 
3.2.5. Please use nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPPOSTagger or 
nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPNERTagger instead.
super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My code looks like this:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

sentence = "Today George went to school and met his friend Peter."

# stanford's NER tagger 3 entity classification
st = StanfordNERTagger('/home/hercules/Desktop/PhD/Tools/stanford-ner-
     2017-06-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
     '/home/hercules/Desktop/PhD/Tools/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-
     ner.jar',
     encoding='utf-8')

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(sentence)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print("Stanford NER tagger:")
print(classified_text)
```

I tried to use CoreNLPNERTagger but I could not find any examples or documentation. 
I only found this [link:](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html)
where it gives something like an example in the comments of the 
class CoreNLPNERTagger(CoreNLPTagger)                                      (I found it by searching the keyword "CoreNLPNERTagge")

I tried to follow that example with no use.
I think I should start (if that is the correct term) the coreNLP server first but if is that the case I don't know how.

If anyone got any idea or advice I would be grateful.

Comment: I upgraded to NLTK 3.3 and the message disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

@imoutidi, I also encountered the same deprecation warning.

After digging around a bit, it looks like the new/replacement package can be imported with the following:

`from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPNERTagger`

However, when trying to run the tag() method I end up getting an unexpected HTTP connection refused error. I haven't figured out if this is an environment configuration issue (missing .jar path) or an issue with the NLTK codebase. I tried temporarily turning off my local firewall and that didn't help, so I'm guessing it is one of the other two possibilities.

I hope the python import statement is at least some help.

[image]

Comment: Yea I tried to import CoreNLPNERTagger with no luck. Maybe when version 3.2.5 will come out there will be a working example.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It looks like there should a server listening at port 9000? Anyone found how to use the Stanford tagger?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on tokyodusk's answer. You should download the stanford Core NLP from [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html)

Then do the following:

- open the terminal
- navigate to where you extracted the package
- type in the following command:
  `java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
  -port 9000 -timeout 15000 -annotators 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner'`

Then do what tokyodusk suggested.